# Определить местоположение процесса по его имени или Pid

Tags: java, c, процесс

Есть имя выполняемого в текущий момент процесса и его Pid. Как мне получить полный(абсолютный) путь к исполняемому файлу этого процесса на java или си?

Comment: В какой операционной системе? Хотите, напишу, как это делается в OS/2? :)

Comment: Например: `sudo readlink /proc/$PID/exe`. На C - [man 2 readlink](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=readlink&category=2&russian=0)

Comment: @Harry а напишите! =)

Comment: @Vartlok Примерно так я когда-то делал - мне нужен был весь список: http://vpaste.net/ocF4V Сейчас уже не вспомню точно, какие вызовы для получения ModuleHandle для Pid, но если это действительно нужно - могу поискать...

Comment: @Harry я про то чтобы вы ответом написали(если не лень), думаю кому-то это может и пригодится.

Comment: Прошу прощения за недальновидность...
Конечно же всё в винде

Comment: @Vartlok Честно говоря, вряд ли :) Будет конкретный вопрос - отвечу, а так...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для винды: OpenProcess() + QueryFullProcessImageName()

Answer (score 2):

Для Linux. Выполнить конвейер команд

```
ps --pid <PID процесса> -f | tail -n1 | awk '{print($8)}'
```

при вызове popen:

```
FILE *ff = popen("Конвейер команд", "r");
```

А затем прочитать строку из файла ff.